# How to find the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+ae^{bx^2}}$

Tags: integration

Could somebody tell me how to find the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+ae^{bx^2}}$$
for constants $a$ and $b$?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with complex analysis ?

Answer (score 12):

I will assume that $a, b$ are positive constants, in order to circumvent singularity issues. By the substitution $z = \sqrt{b} \, x$, the integral in question is equal to

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{a + e^{-z^2}} \; dz.$$

From the identity

$$ 1 + x^{2n+1} = (1 + x)(1 - x + \cdots - x^{2n-1} + x^{2n}), $$

we obtain

$$ \frac{1}{1 + x} = 1 - x + \cdots - x^{2n-1} + x^{2n} - \frac{x^{2n+1}}{1 + x}.$$

Now we temporary assume further that $a > 1$, so that $\alpha = a^{-1} \in (0, 1)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{1 + \alpha e^{-z^2}} \; dz
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \alpha^{k-1} e^{-kz^2} - \frac{\alpha^{2n+1}e^{-(2n+2)z^2}}{1 + e^{-z^2}} \right) \; dz \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \alpha^{k-1}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-kz^2} \, dz - \alpha^{2n+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(2n+2)z^2}}{1 + e^{-z^2}} \; dz \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \alpha^{k-1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}} - \alpha^{2n+1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(2n+2)z^2}}{1 + e^{-z^2}} \; dz
\end{align*}$$

Now taking $n\to\infty$, the remainder term vanishes. Hence we have

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{1 + \alpha e^{-z^2}} \; dz
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} \alpha^{k-1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}
= -a \sqrt{\pi} \, \mathrm{Li}_{1/2} \left( -\tfrac{1}{a}\right),$$

where

$$ \mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^s}$$

is the polylogarithm of order $s$, primarily defined on $|z| < 1$. Although we have proved this identity only for $a > 1$, the equality above can be used to define an analytic continuation of the right hand side, thus (by tautology) it holds for all $a > 0$.

It has special value at $\alpha = 1$, given by

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{z^2}} \; dz
= -\sqrt{\pi} \, \mathrm{Li}_{1/2}(-1)
= \sqrt{\pi} (1 - \sqrt{2}) \zeta \left( \tfrac{1}{2} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + a\expo{bx^{2}}}:\ {\large ?}\,.
     \qquad a>0\,,\quad b> 0.}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + a\expo{b x^{2}}}}
> ={2 \over \root{b}}\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + a\expo{x^{2}}}}
> ^{\ds{x \equiv t^{1/2}}}\ =\
> {2 \over \root{b}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over  a\expo{t} + 1}
> \,\half\,t^{1/2 - 1}\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \root{b}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {t^{\color{#f00}{\large 1/2} - 1}\over
> \expo{t}/\color{#f00}{\large \pars{1/a}} + 1}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over \root{b}}\,\bracks{-\Gamma\pars{\half}{\rm Li}_{1/2}\pars{-\,{1 \over a}}}
> \end{align}
>   The last integral is a
>   [well known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) PolyLogarithm $\ds{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ integral representation.

Since $\ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}$:
$$
\color{#77f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + a\expo{b x^{2}}}
=-\ \root{\pi \over b}\ {\rm Li}_{1/2}\pars{-\,{1 \over a}}}
$$